# Need to clean buffer? x86 linux assembler

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I've got an annoying problem with my program. This is part of the code

```
section .bss
input resb 1

section  .data
sys_open equ 5
sys_write equ 4
sys_read equ 3
sys_exit equ 1
stdout equ 1
stdin equ 0
```

some code

```
leerInput:
push ebx
push ecx

mov eax, sys_read
mov ebx, stdin
mov ecx, input
mov edx, 1
int 80h

pop ecx
pop ebx
cmp byte[input],'s'
je avanzarLinea
cmp byte[input], 'e'
jne exitA
jmp avanzarPantalla
```

Now im going to describe the problem trying to be clear. First the program write some lines from a .txt in console, then call `leerInput`. If user presses the key <kbd>s</kbd> the program write one more line from .txt and call `leerInput` again (until eof). With <kbd>e</kbd> is similar but program write 5 lines and call `leerInput`... Like a small version of command "more". If user presses another key, call `exitA` and print error message. My problem is that, the first time the program call `leerInput`, work fine but the second call (after press <kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>s</kbd> and program write 1 or 5 more lines) the program write error message (jump to `exitA`) before user click any key. I think is something related to buffer but im new with assembly, and the only thing i found related to flush is 134 syscall but don't know if is usefull...

Answer (score 0):

Good try, but syscall 134 won't help you. The annoying problem is that `sys_read` from `stdin` doesn't return until "enter" is pressed. If the pesky user types more characters than you allow in `edx` the excess stays in the OS's buffer (think of it as the "keyboard buffer") ready to be read by the next `sys_read`. The very easiest fix would be to allow two bytes in your buffer, and 2 in `edx` - one for the character you want, and one for the linefeed generated when "enter" is hit. You're still in trouble if the user types more than that.

As you suspect, you want to flush the buffer. Provide a one-byte "dummy" buffer...

```
mov edx, length
mov ecx, input
mov ebx, stdin
re_read:
mov eax, sys_read
int 80h
; if the linefeed is in our buffer, we're good
cmp byte [ecx + eax - 1], 10 ; or "LF"
jz goodread:
; else, flush the buffer
mov ecx, dummy
mov edx, 1
; ebx should still be okay
jmp re_read
goodread:
```

Something like that. It is also possible to diddle bits and make `sys_read` return after just one key, but it's more complicated.

Comment: That was the solution. I thought that sys_read put away extra chars if you did't give enough space in buffer. Thanks a lot. You save my day